# Can't display array elements in HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am expecting this code to retrieve all the objects in the array and displays them in the rows before the row where the "Add" button is. I do not see the items displayed? Below is the code.­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

The script:

```
var addButton = document.getElementById("add-button");
var textArea = document.getElementById("text");
//to display items
var myArray = [{
    "name": "aaa",
    "level": "A"
}, {
    "name": "bbb",
    "level": "B"
}, {
    "name": "ccc",
    "level": "C"
}];
display();

function display() {
    var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
    var length = myArray.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var row = table.insertRow(i + 1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        cell1.innerHTML = myArray[i].name;
        cell2.innerHTML = myArray[i].level;
    } //end for  
} //end display
```

The HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="body">   

<div id="wrapper">
<table align='center' cellspacing=1 cellpadding=1 id="mytable" border=1>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Type</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="text"></td>

<td>
    <select name="levels" id="levels">
    <option value="A" id="option-1">A</option>
    <option value="B" id="option-2">B</option>
    <option value="C" id="option-3">C</option>
    </select> 
</td>

<td><input type="button" class="add" id="add-button" value="Add"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**The Problem:**

When I open the page in Chrome, I do not see the array elements added to the table and I get this error:

> get-text.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertRow' of null at display (myscript.js:17) at myscript.js.js:9

Comment: Your current code seems to work fine.  What is happening and what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Thank you for telling us your problem.  That leads me to think that `table` is null and that's probably because your javascript is being called before the DOM is loaded.  If that's the case, consider waiting for the document to be ready before calling your JS.

Comment: @larz It is working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just defer your code from running by holding it until the window has loaded up the DOM. You can do this by moving your entire script to just before the `body` closes (`</body>`) or you can do this with the modern, standards-based DOM Event Model that uses `.addEventListener()`:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

var addButton = document.getElementById("add-button");
var textArea = document.getElementById("text");
//to display items
var myArray = [{
    "name": "aaa",
    "level": "A"
}, {
    "name": "bbb",
    "level": "B"
}, {
    "name": "ccc",
    "level": "C"
}];
display();

function display() {
    var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
    var length = myArray.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var row = table.insertRow(i + 1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        cell1.innerHTML = myArray[i].name;
        cell2.innerHTML = myArray[i].level;
    } //end for  
} //end display


});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>

<body id="body">   

<div id="wrapper">
<table align='center' cellspacing=1 cellpadding=1 id="mytable" border=1>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Type</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="text"></td>

<td>
    <select name="levels" id="levels">
    <option value="A" id="option-1">A</option>
    <option value="B" id="option-2">B</option>
    <option value="C" id="option-3">C</option>
    </select> 
</td>

<td><input type="button" class="add" id="add-button" value="Add"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have your code running as soon as it's loaded.

The problem with that is your table may not exist at the point your code is loaded (especially if you're running it locally), so when it tries to get the table, it's not there to get (hence why `table` is `null`).

Instead, you should either use some sort of `ready` function. jQuery's is a very popular option, though you have to import the whole jQuery libary, which may or may not be overkill for your use case. You can also implement your own. There are lots of examples out there. A very simple one is just wrapping your code in a `window.onload` callback:

```
window.onload = () => { // your code goes here }
```

That option will work in a lot of modern browsers.

The other, easier option for this specific case is to simple move your `<script>` tag to write before your closing `</body>` tag. That'll ensure it'll load **after** your table is there.